# When I try to get device location from my class I get error "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: java, android, service, geolocation

Here is my very simple class to get coordinates, it works if I launch from Activity, but when I try to get coordinates from service I get this error in constructor DeviceLocation

```
public class DeviceLocation implements LocationListener {
    private Context mContext;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public DeviceLocation(Context context) {
        mContext = context;

        locationManager =
                (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        try {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000 * 3, 0, this);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code where you are trying to use this from a service.

Comment: I have my class Handler, where I have variable mContext, which has initiated by service. From  class handler I call this 
 DeviceLocation mDeviceLocation = new DeviceLocation(context); - this gives me an error

Comment: Does Handler class extend to any other class? posting your code is the best way instead of describing it

Comment: no, Handler - is just a java class and Service which extended GcmListenerService passes context (this) to my Handler
actually, I think I have solved the problem, it has to be written like this
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000 * 3, 0, this, Looper.getMainLooper());

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I should have written this line

```
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000 * 3, 0, this, Looper.getMainLooper());
```

instead of

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000 * 3, 0, this);
```